# How to achieve various InstanceContextMode service behaviours in gRPC similar to WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, grpc

WCF supports PerCall, PerSession and Single Instance type of Service behaviors.  How can we implement these using gRPC?

Comment: There is nothing like this in gRPC. This behaviour if required is implemented in the hosting layer.

Comment: I am interested in knowing how client can establish a session with the server (PerSession behavior of WCF) , any example for this in gRPC?

Comment: In Grpc,a service always behaves like a singleton,in other words, a single instance of the service class is shared by all clients.